# Is there a hosted SVN provider that offers discussion tools on par with GitHub's?

Tags: svn, hosting, github, collaboration

We use SVN at work (ie. this is *not* an open-source project) and have an off-shore team working in our code. I'd love to be able to communicate better with them and the commenting system provided by GitHub would be perfect.

With GitHub's system I can **start a discussion on any line of code in a commit**.

So, my question: does anyone know of a ***hosted*** SVN provider that has a similar tool?

To be clear, I'm looking specifically for discussion tools that allow convenient discussion about the code. The GitHub tool lets you start a discussion on a line of code in the source browser.

I'm not looking for a formal peer-review tool, but rather a discussion tool designed to foster conversation about the code in a commit.

---

We are using Assembla currently and they don't offer this sort of functionality in either the Trac repository browser or their home-grown repository browser.

---

[Example on YouTube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BDjqQ6_LBJE)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any hosting that provides access to Python. You can use [Trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/) with [discussion plugin](http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/DiscussionPlugin)

Comment: Discussion Plugin doesn't allow one to comment on a line of code in a given commit does it? At least not very smoothly. (I suppose one could create a forum and then reference it somehow...)

Comment: http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracLinks "A particular line of a specific file revision: source:/trunk/COPYING@200#L25"

Comment: Yeah, I'm familiar with the capabilities of Trac. What I'm looking for is not the basic capability to reference things but, rather, a method of fostering communication which is on par with the GitHub offering. Theirs is damn-near friction free.

Comment: Ok, I've seen the video. http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/PeerReviewPlugin perhaps? Little less eye-candy, but seems to have same functionality

Comment: Not quite the same. That is a Peer Review, I'm looking for a discussion tool. The problem with a peer review concept is that you first have to say "I want to have a conversation" and /then/ you can have one. Peer Reviews have their place, but they solve a different problem than I'm trying to solve.

Comment: BTW, thanks for engaging in a conversation on this. I've voted your answer up so you at least get the rep for this. (Even though it's not quite an answer to my problem.)

Comment: Well, on the other hand good thing about Trac and it's plugins, is that they are easy to adapt to your needs. So if you do not find what you're looking for, you might consider that option.

Answer (score 3):

It would not be hosted, but you can setup the open source version of the Google Code Review tool previously noted by @SilentGhost which is named Rietveld:
http://code.google.com/p/rietveld/

As is, it runs on Google AppEngine.  You could host this yourself using the AppEngine SDK and Apache's mod_proxy, though I wouldn't recommend this if the site is to be publicly visible as the SDK clearly notes that it is not meant for production and as such security is lightly considered.

Alternatively, Google has also released a tool for converting AppEngine applications into pure Django applications, which you could then host via your favorite python web run time.  On top of this, the demo application conversion that's included is actually Rietveld so they have already taking care of this for you.  See here for more info:
http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/pure_django.html

Answer (score 2):

What about using [Review Board](http://www.review-board.org/)?
It's quite easy to put un place, you can easily restrict the access through password and it can be interfaced with SVN.

I know it's not a hosted service, but putting it in place is so easy that it should not be a show-stopper.

Comment: A lot of good stuff there. The problem is the work-flow. It's a code review system and requires that a review be requested. Way too formal to be a friction-free communication system.
I like the look of it though, It'd be nice to have that commenting system elsewhere...

Comment: I used ReviewBoard for a project last semester, and while it did the job, it wasn't mature enough, I found, for real production type use. Lots of bugs and problems.

Answer (score 1):

Google code provides [CodeReview](http://code.google.com/p/support/wiki/CodeReviews) functionality, which includes possibility of line-by-line commenting as well as whole-commit comments.

Comment: Sounds close, but we are not an open source project.

Answer (score 1):

I think [Beanstalk](http://beanstalkapp.com/) is the best out there for hosted Subversion.

I think you should use git-svn and convert your subversion repository to Git and use github, but Beanstalk is by far the best in terms of features.

All the best

Comment: I too was going to suggest Beanstalk, however this does *not* address the poster's question.  He's looking for the code commenting feature, which as far as I can see in my account, Beanstalk does not have.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend [svnrepository.com](http://svnrepository.com/). It installs [trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/) for you to manage your project.

Comment: Trac does not provide the type of functionality I'm after.

Answer (score 0):

While it's not a line-based system, you could set up a discussion by commit situation using [cvsdude](http://cvsdude.com/screenshots/subversion-hooks.html) with hooks for [Basecamp](http://www.basecamphq.com/tour).  It's a hosted solution and you can also use Lighthouse or even FogBugz to work with it.  Granted, it's probably more meant for bug fixing than communication with teams per se, but I think the Basecamp integration might work for a general solution.  Not perfect but I like it so I thought I'd throw it out there.

I don't think there's anything out there right now that has the line-by-line of Github - perhaps that'd be a good project to start!  Actually cvsdude does offer an API for their Enterprise service, so if you wanted to build your own basic discussion system you could do it off of that I suspect (haven't looked too closely at it myself).

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use [Assembla](http://www.assembla.com). You can get [Subversion Repository http://www.assembla.com/catalog/12-Enhanced-Subversion-Repository-Package](http://www.assembla.com/catalog/12-Enhanced-Subversion-Repository-Package) with just one click and you can later add a lot of extra tools in case you need them:

## Repositories

- [Subversion - with secure EC2 hosting, beautiful browser](http://www.assembla.com/catalog/1-Most-Popular---Subversion-Hosting-with-Integrated-Tickets-Package)
- [Git - with the beautiful browser](http://www.assembla.com/catalog/21-Git-with-Integrated-Tickets---Recommended-Package)
- Mercurial
- Github
- Your SVN server

## Tickets / Issues

- Assembla agile Ticket and Issue tracker
- Trac, enhanced with team and alert management

## Collaboration

- Assembla Wiki
- Assembla Messages
- Assembla Files
- Assembla Chat
- Trac Wiki

## Time Tracking

- Project time report
- Rollup time report
- Burndown chart
- Desktop time tracker

## Management

- Visible activity stream with email alerts and RSS
- Scrum report
- Project templates
- Branded home pages and spaces
- Portfolio reports

## Integration

- REST API
- Webhooks - post to any REST interface
- Twitter
- Eclipse Mylyn
- External SVN, Github

Comment: I already said we use Assembla and it doesn't provide the required functionality...

Comment: They plan to add code review for integrated code browser in near future:
http://www.assembla.com/spaces/ruby-code-browser/tickets/186-%5BMaster-Ticket%5D-Design-Code-Review-Tool

You also can request to install custom plugin for your trac tool if you need it for code review.

Answer (score 0):

You can checkout [InDefero](http://www.indefero.net), it is not providing the line by line review of code but this is on the roadmap for September 2009 or earlier. Note that I am a developer of InDefero.